# ngModel that points to dynamic html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind-html

I have a repeater setup that looks like this

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr ng-repeat="m in resp.AvailableTemplates">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="m.Selected" />
            <span ng-bind-html="m.MessageText"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where m.MessageText is a string that looks something like

```
Hello <input type='text' value=''/>!, thanks for the <input type='text' value=''/>
```

The user will see a list of template phrases, check off the desired phrases, fill in the text areas, and submit which sends an email filled in with the phrases provided.

By using ng-bind-html, the output looks as it should. But when using ng-model, the output doesn't display the html. How can I bind this information so it renders as proper html, but also allows me to gather the information provided by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span ng-bind-html="{{m.MessageText}}"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need the provided html

```
Hello <input type='text' value=''/>!, thanks for the <input type='text' value=''/>
```

to be binded to your angular model, something like

```
Hello <input type='text' value='' ng-model="m.messageContentOne"/>!, thanks for the <input type='text' value='' ng-model="m.messageContentTwo"/>
```

BUT you cant render HTML that contains angular bindings with ng-bind-html (well, you can, but the bindings will not work)

To make it work, you need to bind AND COMPILE the HTML to make the angular bindings work.

To do this you can use the custom directive bind-html-compile, from this link
https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile

You can also do it yourself, you just need to create a directive that compiles the directive element with the angular $compile service

```
 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Hope it helps.